# incorrect id generation for modules in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

webpack generate incorrect bundle.
What`s wrong?

[webpack.config.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-pond-heurp?file=/src/index.js)

```
        }, 2
    c88e: (t, r, a) => {
        "use strict";
        var o, i = a(82109), u = a(31236).f, s = a(17466), v = a(3929), m = a(84488), _ = a(84964), R = a(31913),
            j = "".startsWith, M = Math.min, W = _("startsWith");
        i({
```

[image]

[issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13010)

Comment: Please do not post code in an image. Instead edit the question and add a [mcve] using text.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but it might be easier for you to post your question here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/) fix my problem

> If you are using webpack v5 or above you do not need to install this plugin. Webpack v5 comes with the latest terser-webpack-plugin out of the box. Using Webpack v4, you have to install terser-webpack-plugin v4.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem and solved it. May be you have overlapping while build up project. To solve this I've changed length of hash subsitution in file names in my Webpack config file. I had

```js
output: {
  filename: 'assets/[name]_[contenthash:5].js'
}
```

where `contenthash` was 5 length. It's not enough! I had been suggested to change to 8 symbols of hash length

```js
output: {
  filename: 'assets/[name]_[contenthash:8].js'
}
```

and this solved my problem.

Discussion with Webpack community about it: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/16513

About Webpack output config param and subsitutions: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename